# Error in impute() in R

Tags: r, missing-data

I'm learning Random Forest. For learning purpose I'm using following link [random Forest](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/machine-learning/machine-learning-algorithms/tutorial-random-forest-parameter-tuning-r/tutorial/). I'm trying to run the code given in this link using my R-3.4.1.
But while running the following code for missing value treatment

```
mp2 <- impute(data = test,target = "target",classes = 
list(integer=imputeMedian(), factor=imputeMode()))
```

I'm getting error message `Error in impute(data = test, target = "target", classes = list(integer = imputeMedian(),  : 
  unused argument (data = test)`
I modified the code & try running this

```
imp2 <- impute(test,target = "target",classes = list(integer=imputeMedian(), factor=imputeMode()))
```

Still I'm getting the error but the error message is different. Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key mistake (among *many* mistakes) in that code was that there is no `data` parameter. The parameter name is `obj`. When I change that the example code runs.

You also need to set `on=` or `setkey` given that the object is a `data.table`, or simply change it to a data.frame for the imputation step:

```
imp1 <- impute(obj = as.data.frame(train),target = "target",classes = list(integer=imputeMedian(), factor=imputeMode()))
```